# Sort Group by query based on JSONB first values

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb, unnest

I'm working with PostgreSQL and I have the following SQL query

```
    WITH A AS
(
    SELECT *,
    jsonb_array_elements(event_days) as event_days_arr
    FROM event
)
SELECT event_id::int, 
    MAX(area_id)::int AS area_id, 
    array_agg(event_days_arr) as event_days
FROM A 
WHERE
    event_days_arr->>'start_datetime' >= '2020-12-22' AND
    event_days_arr->>'end_datetime' < '2020-12-22T19:00:00'
GROUP BY event_id, event_alias
ORDER BY 
    (event_days_arr->0->>'start_datetime'),
    (event_days_arr->0->>'end_datetime');
```

As you can see, I have an array called "event_days", and I would like to sort the results based on keys in the first element of that array

For some reason, I have the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "a.event_days_arr" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I've tried with event_days, event_days_arr, but I'm not able to order the result of my query based on the first element of the JSONB array for each row

Anyone can help me sorting this query's result, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the WHERE condition for the time range into the common table expression, which can be done once the set returning function is used in the FROM clause (where it should be used):

The outer aggregation should also be done using `jsonb_agg()` not `array_agg()` as the `->` operator is only defined for JSON arrays, not for native arrays.

A column alias can only be used "as is" in the ORDER BY part. If you want to use an expression you need a second level, e.g. with a derived table or CTE:

```
WITH A AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM event
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(event_days) as arr(event_day)
  WHERE arr.event_day ->> 'start_datetime' >= '2020-12-22' 
    AND arr.event_day ->> 'end_datetime' < '2020-12-22T19:00:00'
)
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT event_id::int, 
         MAX(area_id)::int AS area_id, 
         jsonb_agg(event_day) as event_days
  FROM A 
  GROUP BY event_id, event_alias
) t
ORDER BY event_days -> 0 ->> 'start_datetime',
         event_days -> 0 ->>'end_datetime'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group by the first element of `event_days`, not of `event_days_arr`.

Doesn't this just work?

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT *, jsonb_array_elements(event_days) as event_days_arr
    FROM event
)
SELECT event_id::int, 
    MAX(area_id::int) AS area_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(event_days_arr) as event_days
FROM A 
WHERE
    event_days_arr ->> 'start_datetime' >= '2020-12-22' AND
    event_days_arr ->> 'end_datetime'   <  '2020-12-22T19:00:00'
GROUP BY event_id, event_alias
ORDER BY 
    event_days -> 0 ->> 'start_datetime',
    event_days -> 0 ->> 'end_datetime';
```

Postgres should be able to recognize the the `order by` columns are dependent on `event_id`. If it doesn't, then you would need to add the columns to the `group by` clause:

```
GROUP BY event_id, event_alias, event_days -> 0 ->> 'start_datetime', event_days -> 0 ->> 'end_datetime'
```

Comment: What I was trying to do is group by event_id and event_alias, like I was doing. Trying to group by an array of datetimes.... It sounds me so weird, but thanks for your attention

Comment: One more thing, I've found that if you use "array_agg" function, and you try to sort by its elements, even if the group by let you to do it, you need to access first element of event_days like: "event_days[0]->>'start_datetime'", not like I put it earlier "event_days -> 0 ->> 'start_datetime'"